# start async loop "deatached"

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

module.py

```
queue = asyncio.Queue

async def foo()
   while True:
       val = await queue.get()
       someprocessing(val)

def bar(val)
     queue.put_no_wait(val)
```

I want to call bar method from outside the module and asynchronously process goten values. What additional initialization I need?

Comment: What do you mean by "asynchronously process"? Are you running the event loop in your application? Also note that `queue = asyncio.Queue` is incorrect, you need to "call" the class to instantiate it: `queue = asyncio.Queue()`.

Comment: Please see standard producer-consumer asyncio example:
https://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/producer_consumer.html#simple-example

And clarify your question in case anything else is needed.